# How to correctly input binary from a file

Tags: c++, binary, fstream

I am trying to make a hex editor and I want to read from a file. I am using *fsteam* for this. I am still not very familiar to this library, so I am not sure what I did wrong.

What I am trying to do is to read the first 8 bits(1 byte) of the file as binary and then convert it into hex and display it. My problem is that I am not sure how to get the 8 bits. The code bellow fills the char array with the first char of the file ("H").

```
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>

using namespace std;


int main()
{
    string path = "c:/users/sjames/desktop/s.txt";
    vector<char> buffer(1, 0);

    fstream file;
    file.open(path, ios::binary | ios::in);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        file.read(&buffer[0], buffer.size());
        for (int i = 0; i < buffer.size(); i++)
        {
            cout << buffer[i, 0] << endl;
        }
        file.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: 8 bits or 8 bytes (chars)? Concerning "I am not sure what I did wrong", I don't either. Problem is, nobody here knows what you expected and what you got instead. Please, as a new user here, take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: I want to read 8 bits or 1 byte. And I want to input it in binary.

Comment: `cout << buffer[i, 0] << endl;` is not doing what you think it's doing. First, the expression `i, 0` is evaluated left-to-right, and the right most value `0` is returned. This is equivalent to `cout << buffer[0] << endl;`

Comment: @SJames What made you believe that `std::istream::read()` reads 8 single separate bits from the file? One byte is one byte.

Comment: Is there a way to get the data in binary form? Instead of H - 01001000. Or do I have to convert it myself?

Comment: @JohnFilleau What is the correct way to do it then?

Comment: If by "it" you mean "print the `i`'th element of `buffer`", then `cout << buffer[i] << endl;` But this is now moot since you edited your question. You don't need a loop at all in this situation. Or even a vector. Just a simple `char` would do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I want to read 8 bits or 1 byte. And I want to input it in binary.

So, then simply `read()` 1 byte. The code you have shown is `read()`'ing 8 bytes instead. A `char` is 1 byte, and you are creating a `vector` with 8 `char`s in it.

Try this instead:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "c:/users/sjames/desktop/s.txt";
    unsigned char b;

    ifstream file(path, ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        if (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&b), 1))
            cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned short>(b) << endl;
        file.close();
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Which you can then expand on to display *multiple* bytes as needed:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <fstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
#include <iomanip>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    string path = "c:/users/sjames/desktop/s.txt";
    vector<unsigned char> buffer(...); // TODO: query the file's size, perhaps...

    ifstream file(path, ios::binary);
    if (file.is_open())
    {
        if (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size()))
        {
            size_t numRead = file.gcount();
            for (size_t i = 0; i < numRead; ++i)
            {
                cout << hex << setw(2) << setfill('0') << static_cast<unsigned short>(buffer[i]) << endl;
            }
            file.close();
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

FYI, notice the type-casts to `unsigned short` when using `operator<<`. This is because `std::ostream` has overloaded `operator<<`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ostream/operator_ltlt2) to treat `[(un)signed] char` values as text], not as numbers.  So, if you want to print out a `char` as a number, even in hex format, you need a cast the `char` to a non-`char` numeric type.

Comment: After writing *1, 0* in the buffer size I get an error "argument of type 'unsigned char*' is incopatible with parameter of type 'char*'" in the second if statement if(file.read(**buffer**.data(), buffer.size()))

Comment: This works, thanks! But why do you make the buffer an unsigned char?

Comment: I have updated my examples. I used `unsigned char` because that is the most common type used for *binary* data (before [`std::byte`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/byte) was introduced in C++17, but it is also based on `unsigned char`). A plain `char` is either `signed` or `unsigned` depending on compiler implementation. But binary data is arbitrary, it knows knowing about signs. Using `unsigned char` makes that more explicit.

Comment: Your code worked perfectly with normal text, but when I tried opening an exe file, the readings weren't right some of the time. If you try this string(convert this to ASCII 4d 5a 90 20 and put it in a file. I can not paste it here in ASCII 
- https://www.rapidtables.com/convert/number/hex-to-ascii.html) you get wrong values. Expected values: 4d 5a 90 20. Values I got: ffbf 20 20 ffc2. After some debugging I found out that the line if (file.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(buffer.data()), buffer.size())) got negative values in the buffer when I get the weird values.

Comment: What you describe about negative values is simply not possible with **unsigned** types, only with **signed** types. `ffbf` is the result of *sign-extending* a `signed` char `0xBF` to a `signed short`, and `ffc2` is the result of *sign-extending* a `signed` char `0xC2` to a `signed short`. Even then, there is simply no way you can get a result of `ffbf 20 20 ffc2 ffb8 20 20 20 20` (which is clearly NOT from an EXE file) from a file containing actual bytes `4d 5a 90 20 03 20 20 20 04` (which IS from an EXE file), which means you are doing something wrong outside of the code I have given you.

Comment: I found the problem. the vector declaration was a normal char array, not unsigned. I did that because it was giving me errors before you edited your post the last time. When getting your edited code I forgot to change it back. It works now. Sorry for all the trouble and thanks for helping =)